# Enumerate zipped contents of unzipped folder

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to enumerate the zipped folders that are inside an unzipped folder using `Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath)`.
The problem I have is that it does not seem to be finding the zipped folders, when I come to iterate over the `string[]`, it is empty.

Is `Directory.GetDirectories()` the wrong way to go about this and if so what method serves this purpose?

Filepath example: `C:\...\...\daily\daily\{series of zipped folder}`

```
public void CheckZippedDailyFolder(string folderPath)
      {
          if(folderPath.IsNullOrEmpty())
              throw new Exception("Folder path required");

          foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath))
          {
              var unzippedFolder = Compression.Unzip(folder + ".zip", folderPath);

              using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(unzippedFolder + @"\" + new DirectoryInfo(folderPath).Name))
              {
                  var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
                  var field = csv.GetField(0);
                  Console.WriteLine(field);
              }

          }
      }
```

Comment: `Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\path\to\folder")` returns a string[] of the **folders** in the specified folder. If you want a list of **files** in a folder, you should use `Directory.GetFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. Also, remember that 'zipped folders' are files (ZIP files), not 'real folders'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetDirectories is the wrong thing to use. Explorer lies to you; zip files are actually files with an extension .zip, not real directories on the file system level.

Look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (ZipArchive.Entries) and/or
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (ZipFile) to see how to deal with them.

Comment: I wouldn't say it *lies* to you. When you compress something into zip format, it looses it's folder property and becomes a file. You're right otherwise, GetDirectories is not correct. You need to iterate over all files with extension .zip